# Docker compose: unable to connect to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, go

I have `Go` as my `API` and `PostgreSQL` as my database.

I can run my backend using the docker container when executed in development environment. However, when I run my `dockerfile` and docker-compose. The database is not connecting to `postgres`.

**Dockerfile**

```
    FROM golang:alpine
    RUN mkdir /backend
    ADD . /backend/
    WORKDIR /backend
    COPY go.mod .
    COPY go.sum .
    COPY .env .
    RUN go mod download
    RUN go build -o main .
    EXPOSE 3002
    CMD ["./main"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  postgres:
    image: "postgres"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    restart: always
    networks:
      - "backend.network"


  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - 'postgres'
      - 'backend'
    networks:
      - "backend.network"


  backend:
    build: "."
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres
    restart: "always"
    networks:
      - "backend.network"




networks:
  backend.network:
```

**.env**

```
DB_HOST=localhost
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
POSTGRES_NAME=db
```

**Go connection**

```
DB, err = gorm.Open("postgres", fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", config.Config("DB_HOST"), port, config.Config("POSTGRES_USER"), config.Config("POSTGRES_PASSWORD"), config.Config("POSTGRES_NAME")))
    

    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
```

**Error**

```
failed to connect databasedial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused
exit status 1
```

I really don't know what's wrong with my dockerfile.

Comment: @Irene Print out or log that `err` (not just `panic()` because of it) and post it here. It will give you (and us) clue what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for that @blami , the actual error is not displaying when run docker-compose up. However, i tested to stop the docker container for postgres and run main.go. in my development environment. It says

failed to connect databasedial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused
exit status 1

Comment: Your backend is trying to connect to localhost which will never work as DB is running in different container. Your `DB_HOST` will need to point to that container.

Comment: I also tried pointing and changing my DB_HOST to postgres as the name of the service. However, it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @blami pointed out, the DB_HOST should be "postgres". Also, you are passing the .env file to the postgres image but not to the backend one (it may be using default values). If it keeps failing please comment the error you get.

Finally I would recommend to use a builder image to compile your server and then copy it to a smaller image using alpine (if you want to go a step further you can build the final image from scratch), making the container size as lightweight as we can, just like this:

```
FROM golang:1.15-alpine as builder

COPY . /backend

WORKDIR /backend

RUN go build -o main -ldflags="-s -w" . # If you are building the image below from scratch specify the CGO_ENABLED=0 env var

-----

FROM alpine:3.12.1

COPY --from=builder /backend/main /usr/bin/

EXPOSE 3002

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/main"]
```

**Dockerfile notes** based on [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices) article:

- Try to specify images version whenever possible as the lastest one may introduce new bugs to your app. However, it's not strictly required.
- Prefer COPY to ADD when the resource we are trying to copy is not an url.
- If the purpose of the container is purely running a server it's recommended to use ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD, which will ignore any parameters passed when running the container (if you want to use "exec" command then CMD is preferred).

**Go binary** note: -ldflags="-s -w" is often used to reduce the binary size by stripping the debugging information (more info [here](https://blog.filippo.io/shrink-your-go-binaries-with-this-one-weird-trick/)).

Comment: Thank you @Gaston Palomeque. I got my container running. However, there's another error occurred.

It says

 2021/02/03 05:59:37 exit status 1

Comment: Hi Gaston, yes you may. How can I communicate with you? Do you have whatsapp or messenger?

Answer (score 1):

as @blami said:
your backend is trying to connect to "**localhost**" as each of your containers will have **its own "localhost"**.
youc can use your machine host ip, or your database container ip. you can find it using docker inspect <container_name>